# Drupal 7 Apachesolr: hook_apachesolr_query_prepare() not being called?

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-7

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now. I've tried everything I can think of but can't seem to get the hook **hook_apachesolr_query_prepare()** to fire. Here is the code I'm calling in my template.php file:

```
/**
* Implements hook_apachesolr_query_prepare().
*/
function pz_apachesolr_query_prepare(DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query) {
    echo "Query Prepare Test";
    $query->setAvailableSort('entity_id', array(
        'title' => t('Node ID'),
        'default' => 'asc',
    ));
    $query->setAvailableSort('ds_changed', array(
        'title' => t('Changed Date'),
        'default' => 'asc',
    ));
 }
```

hook_apachesolr_query_alter() works fine, but I don't think I can add sort options (which is my ultimate goal here).

I've tried:

- Completely clearing and reindexing the site
- Flushing all caches multiple times
- Commenting out cache in the solrconfig.xml files
- Disabling and re-enabling search modules

I'm on Drupal 7 using Apachesolr 7.x-1.7.

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing

Comment: have you tried to put an exit() instruction a the end of hook too see if hook_apachesolr_query_prepare() is executed ?

Comment: @Fky yea, I've tried both die() and exit() as well as echoing out statements, doesn't change anything..

Comment: Okay, hum.. Have you tried to put this hook in module file instead of template.php ?

Comment: This did it. I added it to a custom module and it's firing correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Yes !! I'm glad to read it !! i used to put hook into modules instead template.php because i had a lot of trouble , so i think it resolve a lot of hook execution :)

Comment: I think template.php able to receive theme hook and core but not module hooks , maybe template.php is called before loading modules ! i'm not sure but it can explains that issue ^^

Comment: Yea, I had read that the order of execution matters -- I had tried messing with the weights of the modules in the database but that didn't work. I just created a custom module for this specific site and I plan on keeping all of my custom apachesolr code there. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Well ! You're welcome :)